# Bind RACComand to UIViewController event

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, binding, reactive-cocoa

I'm implementing RAC with MVVM pattern in my project and now I came into a doubt.
I have many calls to the server, but all of them are associated to an UIButton and handled in my ViewModel; now I need to make a call to the server when the UIViewController is loaded. Before MVVM I just created a signal in the viewDidLoad method an *voilá!*, but I'm not sure if is ok to put this in the ViewController.
Now I don't know how to bind a RACSignal to an event in my ViewController, and worst of that, I'm not sure if that is the way following the MVVM pattern.

What I'm doing right now when I make a call to server coming from a user action(from a UIButton) is this:

ViewController*

```
self.someButton.rac_command = viewModel.executeSomeAction
//On success:
self.viewModel.executeLoginCompleted.skip(1).subscribeNextAs {
  (isExecuting: Bool) -> () in
  //Do something
}
//On error:
self.viewModel.executeSomeActionError.subscribeNextAs {
  (error: NSError) -> () in
  //Dd something
}
```

ViewModel*

```
var executeSomeAction: RACCommand?
var executeSomeActionError: RACSignal!
var executeLoginCompleted: RACSignal

executeSomeAction = RACCommand(enabled: combineValidationSignals) {
  (any:AnyObject!) -> RACSignal in
  println("ANY: \(any)")
  return self.executeLoginRequest()
}

executeSomeActionError = executeLogin!.errors
executeLoginCompleted = executeLogin!.executing
```

How should I create a RACSignal or RACCommand when the UIView did load? Of course, following the MVVM pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One more hacky than the other but easier to implement accross your app.

**Option 1:**

You can write an extension to UIViewController that uses associatedObjects to add a `viewDidLoadCommand: RACCommand` property to UIViewController. You then swizzle the `viewDidLoad()` method of UIViewController so that it executes your command on `viewDidLoad()`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var ViewDidLoadCommand: String = "ViewDidLoadCommand"
    }

    var viewDidLoadCommand: RACCommand? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.ViewDidLoadCommand) as? RACCommand
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(
                    self,
                    &AssociatedKeys.ViewDidLoadCommand,
                    newValue as RACCommand?,
                    UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    func swizzled_viewDidLoad() {
        self.swizzled_viewDidLoad()

        self.viewDidLoadCommand?.execute(nil)
    }
}

// In the appDelegate

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    method_exchangeImplementations(
        class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, "viewDidLoad"),
        class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, "swizzled_viewDidLoad"))

    return true
}
```

---

**Option 2**

You can just subclass UIViewController and implement the `viewDidLoadCommand`and call it in `viewDidLoad()`

```
class ViewControllerSubClass : UIViewController {
    var viewDidLoadCommand: RACCommand?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewDidLoadCommand?.execute(nil)
    }
}
```

---

Whichever method you choose all you have to do then is set the command in the your custom viewControllers `init` method and and it will get executed on `viewDidLoad`.